# how to $Index get from Javascript side

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to Checked value from $index base. suppose  in textboxStart Index  and TextboxEnd .  when user enter  Start index 5  and End Index 10  , checkbox automatically checked, from 5 To 10 Index. please help me

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in MyList">
    <td>{{$index}}</td>
    <td>
        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="checkbox33">
            <input autocomplete="off" ng-model="item.checked" 
                   type="checkbox" id="checkbox33"
                   class="mdl-checkbox__input" unchecked>
            {{CheckItems()}}
        </label>
    <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.PilgrimID}}</td>
    <td>{{item.GroupName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.PassportNo}}</td>                      
    <td>{{item.Gender}}</td>
    <td>{{item.SubAgentName}}</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ng-change` directive to specify an update function:

```
<div>Input Start
  <input ng-model="inputStart" ng-change="updateSelections(inputStart,inputEnd)" />
</div>
<div>Input End
  <input ng-model="inputEnd" ng-change="updateSelections(inputStart,inputEnd)" />
</div>
```

Then update the selections:

```
$scope.updateSelections = function(iStart, iEnd) {
    $scope.MyList.forEach((x,index)=>item.checked = (iStart<=index && index<=iEnd));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding one property like ItemIndex in your ItemList model,
and by putting input box with display none you can get index value in ItemList and can do what you want from javascript side,

```
<td><input type="text" style="display:none;" ng-model="item.ItemIndex"
           ng-value="$index"/>{{$index}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

just push the selected values in an array , `selectedItemIndexes` like `ng-checked="selectedItemIndexes.includes($index)"`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-snavdn

Comment: i want to inputstart  = 1 and  inputEnd   = 7   .  then automatically  1 to 7 index values are checked